# Insert repeated values without changing the primary key assigned to first non repeated value

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, primary-key

I have newly started learning MySQL and am stuck over a problem.
I have a table with fields :

```
CREATE table clientele(
    client_id mediumint(5) unsigned auto_increment,
    clientname varchar(25),
    product_id mediumint(5),
    orderqty int(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (client_id,product_id)
    )
```

As I am inserting values, the client_id will begin assigning to the every clientname field. In case, I repeat any clientname during insertion, say it has other different field values (product_id/orderqty), it will be assigned a new client_id. How can I keep a single client_id for a single client_name, if there are multiple entries for the same client

Comment: If you're newly started, it's odd that integer declarations would have arguments. Consider upgrading to the latest version

Comment: And you wouldn't typically store a 'product_id' in a table called 'clientele'. Normalise your schema

Answer (score 0):

you can improve your table structure. i suggest following tables to do your task:

```
1. Table: ClientDetails
      columns: clientid, clientname (clientid primary auto increment)

2. Table: Products
        columns: productid, productname ( productid primary key auto increment)

3. Table : ClientOrders
       columns: orderid, productid, clientid, orderQuantity 
( here, orderid is primary key auto-increment and productid clientid will be foreign keys).
```

Now you can use concept of joins to fetch and play with your data as you want.

demo entries:

### Clientdetails:

id,name

1. jhon doe

## Products

id,name

1. Laptop
2. mobile

### ClientOrders

orderid, productid, clientid, orderQuantity

1. 1,1,3
2. 2,1,2

Here jhon doe purchases 3 laptops and 2 mobile.

Answer (score -1):

you  use tow PRIMARY KEY u must use one primary  you have another table product so(product_id) is primary to products table  and fofign key for table  clientele